# How to look at _POST values coming to the controller (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

I read the book "Yii", I can't understand how to look at the global _POST array receiving by controller?

**VIEW**
_form.php

```
<div class="row">
        <?php
            echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id');
            echo CHtml::DropDownList('Page[category_id]','', Category::allCategory(),
                array(
                'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST', //request type
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('subcategory/dynamicSubCategories'), //url to call.
                //Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
                'update'=>'#Page_subcategory_id', //selector to update
//                'data'=>array('category_id'=>'js:this.value'),
                //leave out the data key to pass all form values through
            )));
           echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); 
        ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php
            echo $form->labelEx($model,'subcategory_id');
            echo CHtml::dropDownList('Page[subcategory_id]','', array());
            echo $form->error($model,'subcategory_id');
            ?>
        </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>
```

**SubcategoryController.php**

```
public function actionDynamicSubCategories() {
        $data = Subcategory::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('category_id' => $_POST['category_id']));
        $data = CHtml::listData($data, 'id', 'title');
        foreach ($data as $value => $name) {
            echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name), true);
        }
    }
```

I'm interested in value from view `echo CHtml::DropDownList('Page[category_id]','', Category::allCategory(), ...` which comes to the controller `SubcategoryController.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation into the controller passed this `_POST (Page['category_id'])`.

I use in controller:

```
$x = Yii::app()->request->getPost('Page');
$y = $x['category_id'];

$data = Subcategory::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('category_id' => (int)$y));
```

Solved!

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your controller you can just output the $_POST array.

e.g.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

or

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

This should show you any post values.

Answer (score 0):

To get your _POST variable in Yii, you can use `var_dump(Yii::app()->request->post);`